# MS Access SQL - Most Recent Record for Each Consultant ID

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I have spent some time on StackOverflow looking for this answer and trying a bunch of these solutions without luck. I feel like I am missing something minor but I cannot resolve it. NOTE - Learning SQL and using Access because that is what work uses.

I have 2 tables, 1 has consultant information in it (Columns:Consultant ID, First Name, Last Name, Active (Yes or No Checkbox). The 2nd table has their Weekly Numbers (**Columns:** AutoGenID, Consultant ID, WeekOf (Date), FullService, Consulting, Classified, Reallocations, RecruitmentSrvs) and joined them on ConsultantID (primary key)

I built a simply query to Join the 2 tables and show all the results ONLY for the active consultants in qry_Join (anyone marked not active does not show in this query) qry_Join returns Consultant ID, First Name, & Last Name (From tbl_Consultants) and then WeekOf (Date), FullService, Consulting, Classified, Reallocations, RecruitmentSrvs from tbl_WeeklyNumbers.

**Question:**

I would like to have a query that shows ONLY the most recent WeekOf (Date)entry by each consultant.

**Issue:**

SQL I am using is below but the issue I am having is that if ConsultantID #'s 3, 4, 5, 6, & 7 use a 10/11/2017 date and then ConsultantID #8 uses a 10/12/2017, the query will only return ConsultantID #8's row since it is most recent. I need it to still return all the other consultants most recent rows as well even if they are a date prior to ConsultantID #8s'

**SQL:**

```
SELECT ConsultantID, FirstName, WeekOf, USFullService, USConsulting, Classified, Reallocations, RecruitmentSrvs
FROM qry_Join
Where WeekOf = (SELECT MAX(WeekOf) FROM qry_Join)
```

Comment: Check out DATEPART():

SELECT ConsultantID, FirstName, WeekOf, USFullService, USConsulting, Classified, Reallocations, RecruitmentSrvs
FROM qry_Join
Where DATEPART(wk, WeekOf) = (SELECT MAX(DATEPART(wk, WeekOf)) FROM qry_Join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass ConsultantID to your subquery:

```sql
SELECT ConsultantID, FirstName, WeekOf, USFullService, USConsulting, Classified, Reallocations, RecruitmentSrvs
FROM qry_Join q
Where WeekOf = (SELECT MAX(s.WeekOf) FROM qry_Join s WHERE s.ConsultantID = q.ConsultantID)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this worked great. Just one question, I see you are saying qry_join AS "q", what is the "s" do? How does the system interpret that since I do not dimension (sorry if that is the wrong word) it anywhere?

Comment: Those are aliases. You see that in the query, I use `s.WeekOf`, to make sure I'm using the `WeekOf`field from the query I just named `s`. I'm also comparing `s.ConsultantID` (the `ConsultantID` for the subquery) with `q.ConsultantID` (the `ConsultantID` for the main query). Because I'm using the same query twice, it is needed. Because `s` is out of scope in the main query, it's not needed there (but you can add `q.` before all fields to be more explicit)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  ConsultantID, 
        FirstName, 
        WeekOf, 
        USFullService, 
        USConsulting, 
        Classified, 
        Reallocations, 
        RecruitmentSrvs
   FROM qry_Join INNER JOIN
        (SELECT MAX(WeekOf) maxwkof ,ConsultantID cid
          FROM qry_Join 
          GROUP BY ConsultantID )
   ON ConsultantID = cid  
     WHERE maxwkof = WeekOf
```

The issue in your query is, The below query gives a max date in the whole table. And that max id Matches only one consultant. SO you get one row

```
 WeekOf = (SELECT MAX(WeekOf) FROM qry_Join)
```

The below query will give the max date of each consultant. SO you can join the max date and Consultant ID to get the details for each consultant in their latest weekoff

```
SELECT MAX(WeekOf) maxwkof ,ConsultantID cid
              FROM qry_Join 
              GROUP BY ConsultantID
```

Comment: Being completely new to SQL, is there an advantage to your answer vs. the answer below? I am just trying to understand the difference and how the system is working? Thanks!

Comment: The previous one is called as co related subquery (referencing outer query parameters in subquery) .  In this am collecting all the consultant id and their corresponding max weekoff and then retrieving corresponding results.  The performance, It depends on the database. So you have to run both and select whichever works faster for you.

Comment: `AND  = cid` should be `AND ConsultantID = cid`, you might want to consider moving the `WHERE` condition to an `INNER JOIN`s `ON` condition.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth Thanks for pointing it out. Change WHERE clause to INNER JOINs ON condition:- I feel both are same, are'nt they?

Comment: @Valli The result is, indeed. But if you move it to an `ON` clause, you can more easily join in extra tables (Access doesn't support combining a cross join with any other type of join). I find the query easier to understand that way, too.